# SmsComposeTask feedback

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to send an sms from c# WindowsPhone7/8 like this:

```
SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();
smsComposeTask.To = smsPhonenumberToSend;
smsComposeTask.Body = smsMessageToSend;
smsComposeTask.Show();
```

this works, the sms is sent, 
but after the user accepts (or declines) to send the sms I want to do some calculation in code behind.

Is there a way to attach some callback method and fetch the status of sms composer task?

If this can't be done by the SMScomposer, please guide me if there is any other way in WP to send and sms and get info if it was sent or not.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible.

Comment: there is no way i can get information if user sent the sms or declined??

Comment: Yes, I don't think it's possible. Show() is a void, so you won't have any information from here. And I'm not aware of any mechanism around Tasks that allows things like callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone `Tasks` divide into `Launchers` and `Choosers`. `Choosers` allow you to attach an event handler to execute when the `Task` completes. `SmsComposeTask` is a `Launcher`. You cannot get any information about user's decision. When you want to react to user returning to application after the `Task` completed (whether user send the Sms or not), override `Page.OnNavigatedTo` (using some flag).